# Dissable putty tabcompletion sound

Tags: ssh, putty

When I connect to a Windows computer with ssh to ubuntu server. 
And I use tabcompletion and there are multiple option I hear a geluiid this is sometimes very annoying. Is there a way that I can turn off that sound

Comment: How is this blasphemy? :D

Comment: PuTTy runs on Linux as well as windows, some people, a minority perhaps, use PuTTy on both platforms

Comment: Worst sound ever! Thanks for having already asked this :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you start Putty, go under the Bell tab and configure it the way you wish

[image: Bell]

Save your session ;)

For additional information see http://kb.site5.com/shell-access-ssh/putty-how-to-change-the-bell-style-and-settings/ or the PuTTy documentation of your choice.

Answer (score 7):

Open PuTTY, choose the session you want and click "load".

Now under Terminal, Bell choose:

```
None (bell disabled)
```

Return to session, and click "save".

Open your session and enjoy the silence.